# Trying to return part of a url through regex (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to return a part of the url as a string and add it elsewhere.

So I do something like this:

```
var somestring = $("#hello").attr("href").text().replace(/part\/(\d+)/g, "part-$1");
```

Only I don't think this is correct. What's the correct way to do return the "part-$1" as a string?

Thanks!

Here's the example:

http://jsbin.com/agiyu/edit

If successful the output should be something like Fake Urlpart-333.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var somestring = $("#hello").attr("href").replace(/^.*\/part\/(\d+).*$/g, "part-$1");
$("#hello").append(somestring);
```

- You don't need to call `text()` because `attr()` returns a string.
- You forgot a closing quotation mark.
- Since `$("#hello")` returns a single element, there is no need for `each()`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like this: http://jsbin.com/itaji/edit

It doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: @Mark - the code in your link still contains the first 2 issues: you are calling replace() before text(), and there is a missing quotation mark.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I've revised the example as per your tips:
http://jsbin.com/agiyu/edit
1. OK
2. Got it :)
3. Sorry about that. :)

But it's still not working though. :(

Comment: Thanks Ayman I fixed my initial post. Though the two newer links should be better, as per your suggestions about text() coming first.

Comment: I've just noticed that you actually don't need to call text() at all, since attr() returns a string. I've updated my code.

Comment: Hi, Ayman, the reason why I had text() at the end was because I was just trying to return the replaced string, that is, the part-333 portion, not the entire href. Removing the .text() returns the entire href. Do you know how I can return just the replaced portion and not the entire href without using additional regex (because the actual href I'll end up using is much stranger)?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: OH nevermind, regex works fine!

Thanks!

var somestring = $("#hello").attr("href").replace(/^.+part\/(\d+).+/g, "part-$1");

Comment: I edited my answer according to your latest comment, just to find that you arrived at the same solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

```
document.write(document.location.protocol);
document.write(document.location.host);
document.write(document.location.pathname);
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. If you're saying I use one of those to get parts of the url then that won't really work for me. The href is just an example, I'd really much rather use regex, which works fine anyway!

I apologize in advance if I misinterpreted your hint.